# C++ Code in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH in DllMain is not being executed

Tags: c++, dll, server, client, dllmain

I have a `client` and a `server` written in C++. The `client` is in `dll` and the `server` is in `.exe`. I first start the `server` and then inject the `dll` in the explorer.exe with the `client` in it. When I start the `client` and send a message in the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` then it works fine and `client` and `server` are communicating.

But when I restart the explorer.exe and the `dll` is unloaded meaning that the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` should be called thus meaning that when I start the `client` and send a message to the `server` from `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` then it also should work but it doesn't. I am working on a Windows 10 machine and VS2015.

Here is my code

```
client.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>




// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"


using namespace std;

//==================================================================================================================
int SendMessageToServer();
//==================================================================================================================

INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        //Send message to server that the dll is about to be unloaded
        //works when being called from here
        //SendMessageToServer();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        //Send message to server that the dll is about to be unloaded
        //doesn't work when being called from here
        SendMessageToServer();

        break;

    }

    return true;
}


//=====================================================================================================================
int SendMessageToServer() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;


    char* hostname = new char[sizeof(char*) + 1];
    hostname = "192.168.178.17";
    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(hostname, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);



    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
//==================================================================================================================
```

server

```
server.cpp

#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);



    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't put code in DllMain, it is called during a kernel loader lock and a lot of API calls will not work. Additional reading https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873

Comment: @RichardCritten: See also [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx)

Comment: `char* hostname = new char[sizeof(char*) + 1]; hostname = "192.168.178.17";` - This is a memory leak. You are allocating a memory block, then changing the pointer to point at a new memory address, losing access to the previous block. To copy the hostname value into the allocated memory, use `strcpy()` or equivalent (also, `sizeof(char*)` is the wrong size to use): `char* hostname = new char[16]; strcpy(hostname, "192.168.178.17"); ... delete[] hostname;`  Or, just don't use `new[]` at all: `std::string hostname = "192.168.178.17";` or simply `const char* hostname = "192.168.178.17";`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thanks for that link